# How to get rid of the FPS overlay when pressing CTRL+ALT+S on an Asus ROG laptop?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, asus-laptop, armoury-crate

Whenever I press CTRL+ALT+S, an overlay semi-transparent rectangle, which displays (apparently) FPS graph, appears on the top left corner of my screen:

[image: FPS graph]

The problem is that it blocks this keyboard shortcut, which is common for apps like JetBrains IDEs (PyCharm, IDEA, ...).

It's an Asus ROG laptop, could it be related to that Armoury Crate thing? I looked anywhere in there, but couldn't find any reference to such thing.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: "The problem is that it blocks this keyboard shortcut" -- It can be worse. In Poland this unfortunate overlay affects typing text. In the common Polish keyboard layout Ctrl+Alt+s is equivalent to AltGr+s and this types `ś`, a not-so-rare Polish letter. Problems with `ś` are nothing new, see [*The curious case of the disappearing Polish S*](https://medium.engineering/the-curious-case-of-disappearing-polish-s-fa398313d4df).

Comment: Try [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUSROG/comments/kxozd3/how_do_i_get_hide_or_get_rid_of_this_overlay/) for using GPU tweak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Armour Crate > Device > System > Resource Monitor > Real-time monitor settings

There you can change the shortcut get for that annoying overlay.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Aman you can use the profile page to link your social media, blogs etc, but please [refrain from doing so in your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Stackoverflow/Stackexchange is a bit different as that is not a typical forum with post signatures and so on. That being said, a good first answer otherwise.

Comment: Thank you and welcome aboard  apparently there is no way to get rid of that shortcut (only to change it), which is very annoying!! I'm considering uninstalling that software (Armoury Crate) altogether. Stupid move by Asus 